# The procedure entry point BCryptHash could not be located in the dynamic link library while setting up MongoDB shell

Tags: windows, mongodb, dll

When I tried to setup the MongoDB shell version 4.4.6 in my windows 8 system I am getting the following error:-

The procedure entry point **BCryptHash** could not be located in the dynamic link library D:..\bin\mongo.exe

Is this related to any **dll** file missing my windows system ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [[MS.Docs]: BCryptHash function (bcrypt.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcrypthash) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> **Minimum supported client**        ***Windows 10*** [desktop apps | UWP apps]

Then I checked [[MongoDB.Docs]: Install MongoDB Community Edition on Windows - Platform Support](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#platform-support) which states (***emphasis*** still mine):

> **EOL Notice**
>
> - MongoDB 4.4 Community Edition ***removes support for Windows 8.1*** / Server 2012 R2
> - MongoDB 4.4 Community Edition ***removes support for Windows 8*** / Server 2012
> - MongoDB 4.4 Community Edition removes support for Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2

So, either upgrade to *Windows 10*, either install an older *MongoDB* version.